# Should we prove the well-definedness?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Here is the question I am trying to prove:

Let $h,k : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ be continuous maps. If $h$ and $k$ are homotopic and if the image of the base point $x_0 \in X$ remains fixed at $y_0$ during the homotopy then the induced homomorphisms $h_*$ and $k_*$ are equal.

I know how to prove that $h_* = k_*$ but my professor said that we have to prove well- definedness which I do not know why?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: induced homomorphisms on what?

Comment: @PaulFrost They are maps from $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ to  $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ so they are induced on the fundamental groups

Comment: You should edt your question to include this information. And  well- definedness of what are you supposed to show? I guess that  induced homomorphisms have been treated.

Comment: @PaulFrost my professor is not a good lister to questions, so he just mentioned well definedness and I did not get well definedness of what.  What do you mean by this statement "I guess that induced homomorphisms have been treated."

Comment: I guess that your professor has explained how induced homomorphisms are defined. Given $[u] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$, one defines $h_*([u]) = [f \circ u] \in \pi_1(Y,y_0)$. Here you have to verify well-definedness. But if this was done in class, nothing remains in your question which could not be well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $h_*$ is defined as $[w] \mapsto [h \circ w]$, where $w : (S^1,1) \to (X,x_0)$ is a loop and $[w]$ denotes its homotopy class in $\pi_1$. Suppose we have homotopic loops $w \sim w'$ via a homotopy $H$. Then the map $h \circ H : S^1 \times [0,1] \to X \to Y$ is a homotopy $h \circ w \sim h \circ w'$. This shows that $h_*([w]) = [h \circ w] = [h \circ w'] = h_*([w'])$ and hence $h_*$ is well-defined.

The argument for $k_*$ is the same. I hope this helps!

Comment: why you are writing $(S^1, 1)$ as a domain for the loop $w$ is not its domain is the unit interval?

Comment: @Brain We could have used the unit interval $[0,1]$, but then one always needs to remember to write $w(0)=w(1)$. It's just a bit more convenient to use $S^1$ in my opinion.

Comment: and what is the number $1$ in $(S^1, 1)$ referring to?

Comment: According to my professor advice (He did not give any details), we should have proved the well definedness first before proving that $h_* = k_*$ ...... was his advice correct? I see you are using that $h \circ H$ is a homotopy to prove the well definedness.

Comment: The number $1$ is just some basepoint of $S^1$. We need this because we are considering *based* maps in the definition of $\pi_1$. I guess your professor's advice was good, because otherwise it wouldn't even make sense to talk about these maps $h_*$ and $k_*$.

Comment: but you did not prove that $h \circ H$ is a homotopy in your argument .... you just used it

Comment: It should be easy to prove that $h \circ H$ is a homotopy, just by going through the definition. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: I think I am confusing 2 homotopies now, the homotopy between the $k$ and $h$ (given) and the homotopy between $w$ and $w'$(aasumed) , we have 2 homotopies ,right?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you showed me the proof that $h \circ H$ is a homotopy

Comment: Yes, the homotopy from $h$ to $k$ was given, and the one between $w$ and $w'$ was assumed to exist in order to show well-definedness. To see that $h \circ H : S^1 \times [0,1] \to Y$ is a homotopy between $h \circ w$ and $h \circ w'$, you only have to see that $ (h \circ H)(x,0)=h(w(x))=(h \circ w)(x) $ and $ (h \circ H)(x,1)=h(w'(x))=(h \circ w')(x) $. Moreover, $h \circ H$ is continuous as a composition of continuous maps.

Comment: one last thing (and thanks for your patience), I am not understanding the domain and off course why we are going to $X$ and then $Y$ of the given homotopy, I mean I do not understand this line  $S^1 \times [0,1] \to X \to Y$  of the homotopy $h \circ H$ could u clarify it please? I believe that it should be $S^1 \times X$ not  $S^1 \times [0,1]$

Comment: The domain should be $S^1 \times [0,1]$, because for a homotopy you always need this measure of "time", running from $0$ to $1$. Take a look at the definition of a homotopy if you are unsure about this!